# C++, using a class that have no constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Assuming I have the following code:

```
class RecommenderSystemLoader
{

private:

public:
    RecommenderSystemLoader() = delete;

    /**
     * loads movies by the given format for movies with their feature's score
     * @param movies_file_path a path to the file of the movies
     * @return shared pointer to a RecommenderSystem which was created with those movies
     */
    static std::unique_ptr<RecommenderSystem> create_rs_from_movies_file(const std::string& movies_file_path) noexcept(false);
};
```

Assuming that `RecommenderSystem` is another class.
I was wondering how can I obtain an instance of this class and use the static function `create_rs_from_movies_file` that lies in it, given the fact there is no constructor at all.
I want to do it from the `main.cpp` file.

Comment: You can't create an object that has no constructor at all. But you could make a `private` constructor if you want your static method to be the only thing that can create object of your class.

Comment: `RecommenderSystemLoader r{};` will create an instance of the class in your case.

Comment: When you find you need to do something unusual, examine the problem that led you to the new, unusual problem. There may be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you Anoop Rana, it actually worked!

Comment: @AnoopRana That depends on the standard version.  In C++17, yes, but going forward it wont: https://godbolt.org/z/zT4feEo5d

Comment: It won't work for long.

Comment: @PythonAddict But it shows that whatever you intended to do with `RecommenderSystemLoader() = delete;` doesn't work, anyone can create an instance.

Comment: It's a **static** member function; you don't need an object. Just call it: `RecommenderSystemLoader::create()` (sorry, got bored typing those long names). But this is really a job for a namespace.

Comment: Why aren't you invoking the static method like one usually does? With scope resolution.

Comment: It isn't clear if you are asking about how to call the `static` member function without a constructor (you don't need an instance in that case) or if you are asking about changing the design such that an instance of `RecommenderSystemLoader` can be obtained despite its constructing being private.

Comment: It looks like `RecommenderSystemLoader` should be a namespace

Comment: I can imagine that sometimes you might want for RecommenderSystemLoader to be a class, so that you can refer to create_rs_from_movies_file in abstract way: `T::create_rs_from_movies_file` where `T` can be `RecommenderSystemLoader` or `AnotherSystemLoader`, both having _create_rs_from_movies_file_ method.

The thing is that you don't need an class instance in order to propagate class type. `static create_rs_from_movies_file()` function is part of the type.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about what you are trying to do, it seems to me you are searching for a creational pattern, maybe factory method design pattern.

However, to directly address your question, if you want to call `create_rs_from_movies_file` you don't need to have an instance of `RecommenderSystemLoader` because the method is static.

From a main.cpp you can write:

```
auto rec_sys = RecommenderSystemLoader::create_rs_from_movies_file(path)
```

Answer (score -1):

> how can I obtain an instance of this class

For your given example you can use zero initialization to create an instance of `RecommenderSystemLoader` as shown below:

```
//create an instance 
RecommenderSystemLoader r{};
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/TaRAygz7m)

---

> how can i use the static function create_rs_from_movies_file that lies in it

The  `static` member function `create_rs_from_movies_file` can be called without any object so you don't need to create an instance to use `create_rs_from_movies_file`.

Comment: C++20 has fixed this flaw and this will no longer work going forward.

Comment: I don't recall if this was fixed as a DR or not, but if so, one won't be able to change standard versions to make it work either.

Comment: Didn't that already fail when the class isn't an aggregate type?